The Seekbar value is inaccessible
I'm trying to create my own android application to control my RC car via bluetooth with android studio inguana (I was using the old version).
The problem is that I try to get the value with the Logcat or by displaying the value on the screen of my phone but nothing works.
seeck bar
android:id="@+id/Power"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:max="100"
        android:min="0"
        android:rotation="270"

test view
            android:id="@+id/Mot1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Motor 1:"

java code
package com.example.omnicar;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import com.google.android.material.slider.Slider;
import java.util.List;

public class Joystick extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ConstraintLayout layout = null;
    private String MotorTmp1 = new String();
    private String MotorTmp2 = new String();
    private String MotorTmp3 = new String();
    private String MotorTmp4 = new String();

    private BluetoothGatt gatt = null;
    private List<BluetoothGattService> listGattService = null;
    private List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> listGattCharacteristics = null;
    private String mac = null;
    private String data_reveived = null;

    private Button LeftUp, Up, RigthUp;
    private Button Left, Right;
    private Button LeftDown, Down, RightDown;

    private TextView Motor1, Motor2, Motor3, Motor4;
    private SeekBar Power;
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_joystick);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        //layout = (ConstraintLayout) ConstraintLayout.inflate(Joystick.this, R.layout.activity_joystick, null);
        //button declaration
        Button LeftUp = layout.findViewById(R.id.UL);
        Button Up = layout.findViewById(R.id.U);
        Button RigthUp = layout.findViewById(R.id.UR);
        Button Left = layout.findViewById(R.id.L);
        Button Right = layout.findViewById(R.id.R);
        Button LeftDown = layout.findViewById(R.id.DL);
        Button Down = layout.findViewById(R.id.D);
        Button RightDown = layout.findViewById(R.id.DR);

        //Motor
        TextView Motor1 = layout.findViewById(R.id.Mot1);
        TextView Motor2 = layout.findViewById(R.id.Mot2);
        TextView Motor3 = layout.findViewById(R.id.Mot3);
        TextView Motor4 = layout.findViewById(R.id.Mot4);
        SeekBar Power = layout.findViewById(R.id.Power);

        Intent preIntent = getIntent();
        if (preIntent.hasExtra("macAddress")){
            mac = preIntent.getStringExtra("macAddress");
        }else{
            finish();
        }

        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mac);

        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Joystick.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Preparing to play ...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.show();

        BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
                if (newState == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED){
                    gatt.discoverServices();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog.cancel();
                }
            }

            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @Override
            public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status){
                listGattService = gatt.getServices();
                listGattCharacteristics = listGattService.get(4).getCharacteristics();
                boolean res = gatt.readCharacteristic(listGattCharacteristics.get(0));
                boolean res_bis = gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(listGattCharacteristics.get(0), true);
                BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = listGattCharacteristics.get(0).getDescriptors().get(1);
                descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                if (!gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor)){
                    Log.i("My_ERROR", "problem");
                    return;
                }
            }

            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @Override
            public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic){
                super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
                if (listGattCharacteristics != null){
                    byte[] u = characteristic.getValue();
                    if (u != null){
                        String readMessage = new String(u);
                        data_reveived = readMessage;
                        // receive motor temperature
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status){
                super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
                try {
                    if (listGattCharacteristics != null){
                        byte[] u = characteristic.getValue();
                        if (u != null) {
                            String readMessage = new String(u);
                            Log.i("TEST", readMessage);
                        }
                    }
                }finally {

                };
            }
        };

        gatt = bluetoothDevice.connectGatt(Joystick.this, true, gattCallback);

        Power.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int progressChangeValue = 0;
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                progressChangeValue = progress;
                Log.i("Value", progressChangeValue+"");
                Motor1.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });




/*        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });*/
    }
}

manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Omnicar"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".BLE"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Joystick"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>

Logcat
how can i fix that?
I tried to print the value in the logcat i tried to print it the debug or to display it inside the text view  nothing work

Hello, i have added all the java code

setContentView(R.layout.activity_joystick); having this at end cancels all previous UI initialization.  And not sure why you are inflating the layout as well - just move this line to after super.onCreate.  Remove inflating of layout (that's one purpose of setContentView) and use findViewById (no variable prefix).

Alternatively you could do setContentView(layout) leaving everything else same.

i tried you change and still not working. please take a look at the code i update the java code with you instruction

I'll assume you changed layout.findViewById to just findViewById because it would be a nullpointer otherwise.  Also can it be assumed preIntent.hasExtra("macAddress") is true?   Also, does the progressDialog show - and isn't that displayed overtop the textviews and spinner?  I would add a logcat in the main path such as after Power.setOn... statement - just to verify your logcat filter is working.

You're also "hiding" field variables - for example, by first declaring private SeekBar Power; but then in onCreate you re-declare SeekBar Power = layout.findViewById(R.id.Power); which is a method-local variable and not the field variable; however, I don't see that being an issue with the code you have shown.  I would strip off the SeekBar in the line which initializes it - same for rest.

Thank you very much, its work that was the preIntent
